# moto-server docker image with test container for AWS EC2

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ec2, testcontainers, moto

Moto is Mock AWS Services : https://github.com/spulec/moto

When am trying to test aws ec2 service the GenericContainer for [moto-server docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/motoserver/moto) is failing.

code :

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "us-east-1");
            map.put("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY");
            map.put("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY");
            map.put("service_name", "s3");
            map.put("region_name", "us-east-1");
            map.put("endpoint_url", "http://localhost:5000");

            GenericContainer genericContainer = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(
                "motoserver/moto"))
                .withEnv(map)
                .withEnv("moto_server","ec2")
                .withNetwork(tcNetwork)
                .withExposedPorts(3000);
            genericContainer.start();
```

Could anyone help me here with the parameters required for moto-server

logs :

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:330)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:311)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with different approach :

```
 GenericContainer genericContainer = new GenericContainer(
        DockerImageName.parse("motoserver/moto"))
        .withCommand("ec2").withEnv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY")
        .withEnv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
        .withEnv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "us-east-1")
            .withEnv("port","3000");
```

//            .withExposedPorts(3000);
genericContainer.start();